# Hello everyone Sql Insert with same id but different values in another column?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I need the requirements of inserting multiple rows of same ID

My Table Data:

```
Steam_id Skin_name
steam_id 1 skin_name1
steam_id 1 skin_name2
steam_id 1 skin_name3

steam_id 2 skin_name1
steam_id 2 skin_name2
steam_id 2 skin_name3
```

Required Output Should be,

```
Steam_id Skin_name
steam_id 1 3 ( total number of skin )
steam_id 2 3 ( total number of skin )
```

Please help me to achieve this output.

Thanks.

Comment: By definition, the key (ID) for each row must be unique. Sounds like you want a [composite key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_key#:~:text=In%20database%20design%2C%20a%20composite,key%20in%20its%20own%20right.)

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below script.

```
SELECT Steam_id,COUNT(*) Skin_name FROM Table_case GROUP BY Steam_id
```

[image]

Comment: how to add 3 table 
in 3rd table how to add count